# Wait for file to be uploaded before moving to the next iteration of loop?

Tags: javascript, firebase

I am uploading files to firebase storage inside a loop but the loop does not wait and exits before completing of upload. How can I solve this?

Here is the javascript fuunction I am using:

---

```
       function submitImages() {

                for (var j = 0; j < files1.length; j++) {

                    // Create the file metadata
                    var metadata = {
                        contentType: 'image'
                    };
                    var fname = stid + " - " + files1[j].name;
                    var uploadTask = storageRef.child('student_images/' + fname).put(files1[j], metadata);

                    uploadTask.on(firebase.storage.TaskEvent.STATE_CHANGED, // or 'state_changed'
                        function(snapshot) {
                            var progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
                            console.log('Upload is ' + progress + '% done');
                            switch (snapshot.state) {
                                case firebase.storage.TaskState.PAUSED: // or 'paused'
                                    console.log('Upload is paused');
                                    break;
                                case firebase.storage.TaskState.RUNNING: // or 'running'
                                    console.log('Upload is running');
                                    break;
                            }
                        },
                        function() {

                                uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(function(downloadURL) {

                                console.log('File available at', downloadURL);

                            });


                        });
                }

                alert("Images Uploaded Successfully");

            }
```

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Use [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) in conjunction with [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Like so:

```
async function submitImages() {
  var uploadPromises = [];
  for (var j = 0; j < files1.length; j++) {
    // Create the file metadata
    var metadata = { contentType: 'image' };
    var fname = stid + " - " + files1[j].name;
    var uploadTask = storageRef.child('student_images/' + fname).put(files1[j], metadata);

    uploadPromises.push(
      new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        uploadTask.on(firebase.storage.TaskEvent.STATE_CHANGED, // or 'state_changed'
          function (snapshot) {
            var progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
            console.log('Upload is ' + progress + '% done');
            switch (snapshot.state) {
                case firebase.storage.TaskState.PAUSED: // or 'paused'
                    console.log('Upload is paused');
                    break;
                case firebase.storage.TaskState.RUNNING: // or 'running'
                    console.log('Upload is running');
                    break;
            }
          },
          function () {
            uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL()
              .then(function(downloadURL) {
                  console.log('File available at', downloadURL);
                  resolve()
              });
          }
        );
      })
    )
  }

  await Promise.all(uploadPromises)

  /* Now any code below this line will run only after all uploads are finished successfully */

  alert("Images Uploaded Successfully");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use async loop in order to successfully run the code. Since firebase upload task is async, the loop will not continue once the API returns the success result. Check it out here:

[Javascript async](https://caolan.github.io/async/v3/)
https://caolan.github.io/async/v3/

So for your code it would look something like this:

```
async.eachLimit(files,1,function(image,callback){
 //Your firebase upload code
  uploadTask.on(firebase.storage.TaskEvent.STATE_CHANGED, // or 'state_changed'
                    function(snapshot) {
                        var progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
                        console.log('Upload is ' + progress + '% done');
                        switch (snapshot.state) {
                            case firebase.storage.TaskState.PAUSED: // or 'paused'
                                console.log('Upload is paused');
                                break;
                            case firebase.storage.TaskState.RUNNING: // or 'running'
                                console.log('Upload is running');
                                break;
                        }
                    },
                    function() {

                            uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(function(downloadURL) {

                            console.log('File available at', downloadURL);                  
                            //this is important - tells the async to go 
                           //to the next iteration result
                            callback(null)
                        });


                    });
},function(err){
   // do what you want to after upload everything
}
```